# Error: Workbench Auto-Save Background Job Error

Tags: java, eclipse

This error shows up every 5 minutes:

An internal error occurred during: "Workbench Auto-Save Background Job".
loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/eclipse/emf/common/util/EList"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGCqy.png)

Do you know how can I fix it?